# How to fix an error in java calculator which is lab2 in udacity android developlement course?

Tags: java, android, calculator

I was trying to run this code but it's not working.

You should create a calculator with its basic functions.

Create a calculator class which has sum, subtract, division, and multiply methods, all of them take two int parameters and return the resulted int.

Example: When the sum method is called as sum(5,6), it should return 11 which is the sum of 5 and 6

How can I fix it ?

```
class MyCalculator {
    int input1 = 15;
    int input2 = 5; 
    public float sum() {

        int sum = input1 + input2;
         return sum;
    }

    public float divid() {
        // TODO: write java code to calculate the average for all input variables
       int divid = (input1 / input2);
         return divid;
    }
    public float subtract() {
        // TODO: write java code to calculate the average for all input variables
        int subtract = (input1 - input2);
         return subtract;
    }
    public float multiply() {
        // TODO: write java code to calculate the average for all input variables
        int multiply = (input1 * input2);
         return multiply;
    }

}
```

It gives me this error

```
method sum in class MyCalculator cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: int,int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
method divid in class MyCalculator cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: int,int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
method subtract in class MyCalculator cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: int,int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
method multiply in class MyCalculator cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: int,int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: [tag:xml] has exactly nothing to do with it. Don't tag indiscriminately

Answer (score 0):

In ur each function declaration the type is "float" but you return an "int".So better to update  the both as same.The following are code changes

```
public float sum() {

        float sum = input1 + input2;
         return sum;
    }

    public float divid() {
        // TODO: write java code to calculate the average for all input variables
       float divid = (input1 / input2);
         return divid;
    }
    public float subtract() {
        // TODO: write java code to calculate the average for all input variables
        float subtract = (input1 - input2);
         return subtract;
    }
    public float multiply() {
        // TODO: write java code to calculate the average for all input variables
        float multiply = (input1 * input2);
         return multiply;
    }
```

Then try it

Answer (score 0):

```
 // TODO create class MyCalculator with sum, divid, subtract, multiply
  public class MyCalculator {

  public int sum(int x,int y){
    return x+y ;
  }
  public int subtract(int x,int y){
    return x-y;
  }
  public int multiply(int x,int y){
    return x*y;
  }
  public int divid(int x,int y){
    return x/y;
  }
}
```

Comment: It may not be obvious to everyone why this may answer the Question. Kindly edit your answer and give details to explain how and/or why you think this works, and what caused the solution in the Question to not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to solve the lab

```
// TODO create class MyCalculator with sum, divid, subtract, multiply
class MyCalculator {
    
    int num1 = 5;
    int num2 = 6;
    
    public int sum(int num1, int num2){
        return num1+num2;
    }
    
    public int subtract(int num1, int num2){
        return num1-num2;
    }
    
    public int multiply(int num1, int num2){
        return num1*num2;
    }  
        
    public int divid(int num1, int num2){
        return num1/num2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.